# threading does not work on UDP socket server on recv function with Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, tkinter, python-multithreading

i am quite new to Python, i am trying to create a gui interface to a server and a client that shows the user data and web data.
when i try to create a threathing.Thread to the s.recv function it doesnt stop the server from freezing...
how can i make the server not freeze when he arrives to the s.recv function?
Thanks in advance!

some of my code:

```
def receive_message():
"""
"""
global G
s =socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
G.insert(INSERT, "Welcome to the 'Sniffer' server")
ROOT.update()  # updates the Tkinter form
#time.sleep(1)
G.insert(INSERT, "\n")
while 1:
    data = threading.Thread(target=s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)).start()
    if ("ip" not in format(data.decode()) and format(data.decode()).count('$') == 3):
        sql = format(data.decode())
        sqllist = list(sql.split("$"))
        sqllist = [sqllist]
        sql_connection(sqllist)
    elif ("ip" not in format(data.decode()) and format(data.decode()).count('$') == 4):
        sql = format(data.decode())
        sqllist = list(sql.split("$"))
        sqllist = [sqllist]
        sql_connection2(sqllist)
    if ("$" not in format(data.decode())):
        G.insert(INSERT, format(data.decode()))
        ROOT.update()  # updates the Tkinter form
        time.sleep(1)
        G.insert(INSERT, "\n")
    if not data:
        break
```

Comment: Actually you need to run `receive_message()` in a thread instead of `s.recv()`.  Note that you need to pass *the function reference* to `target` option, but you passed the result of the function in your code. Also `if not data:` should be checked right after calling `s.recv()`.

Comment: Okay, i've tried running the receive_message in a thread but still it's freezing...

Comment: Did you you `target=receive_message` instead of `target=receive_message()`? The later one is still running `receive_message()` in the main thread which causes the freezing.

Comment: Yea i did, the problem is that every time it arrives to s.recv the code waits for a message and until the code receive that message the gui freezes...

Comment: Better update your question with the updated code.

Comment: See [example based on your code](https://pastebin.com/Nx3FUfGR).  The GUI does not freeze.

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there. When you call the `s.recv` function you actually execute it in the main thread and pass the return data to the thread. So, basically, you don't execute the `s.recv` function in a separate thread and this is what causes the server to freeze.

Instead, call the thread like this with arguments.

```
data = threading.Thread(target=s.recv, args=(BUFFER_SIZE,)).start()
```

Comment: `data` is the result of `start()`, not `s.recv(...)`.

Comment: becuase the returning value is None it arrives to the 'if' and breaks the code

Comment: `start()` returns `None` and does not wait for the thread to complete its work. OP's next step is `data.decode()` meaning that the code is written to wait until the data is received. All that happens here is that a receive is silently discarded by a background thread.

Answer (score 0):

There was no need to create a thread here because your code (attempts to) consume the data right away. Your problem is that you *call* `s.recv()` try to use its return value to make a thread. Its just a byte string, not a function, so nothing happens. But there are other problems. The `Thread.start` method returns `None` , not the returned data. In fact, `Thread` will discard the target's return value. You need a different way to save the data. That is moderately difficult and not needed here.

The solution for this code is to skip the thread entirely. There is one more subtle bug here. You want to specifically define what the encoding for your protol is. If you just use the default, that can be different on different machines. And just decode once, no need to wear out your cpu.

```
while 1:
    data = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE).decode('utf-8')
    ...etc...
```

Comment: im sorry but if you suggest to skip the thread entirely what do you suggest that i should do to fix the freezing problem?

Comment: I don't know what GUI toolkit you are using, but the general outline is that this whole routine should be in a thread so that it doesn't block the GUI event loop. You are doing some sql stuff fed from a server sending datagrams I guess (?). If this includes interaction with the GUI then you'd need to post events to the GUI's event loop to make stuff appear on screen.

Comment: The main problem is the recv function because when there is no message to receive the the code will wait until there will be and that is what freezes my GUI .. Do you know of any way to check if there is any connection/message recieved from the client before executing the recv function? I think if i had a way to do that then i could make a loop that would go on until there is a message from the client and in the same time update the GUI so it doesn’t freeze.

Comment: And btw i am using Tkinter